# FragmentPagerAdapter in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I want to show 3 different views in ViewPager and I want to navigate between them with bottom navigation bar. But I have a serious performance problem. When I tried to switch the view, it switches with laggy swipe and I think it's because every fragment is re-created everytime I switch or it's because I didn't figure onPageSelected method out. I couldn't fix it.

Here is my codes.
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private BottomBar mBottomBar;
private User currentUser;
private NonSwipeableViewPager viewPager;
private Context context;
private FragmentAdapter fragAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    // To retrieve object in second Activity
    currentUser = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("currentUser");

    //initialize views
    initView();

    //bottom bar
    mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.noTabletGoodness();
    //mBottomBar.setActiveTabColor(R.color.app_design_color);
    mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_menu);
    mBottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#6c4853");
    //mBottomBar.setBottom(1);

    mBottomBar.setOnMenuTabClickListener(new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomContacts) {
                // The user selected item number one.
                setPage(Constants.CONTACTS_NUM);
            }else if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomQR) {
                // The user selected item number two.
                //setAdapterClick(Constants.ADD_NUM);
            }else if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomProfile) {
                // The user selected item number three.
                setPage(Constants.PROFILE_NUM);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

            if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomContacts) {
                // The user selected item number one.
            }else if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomQR) {
                // The user selected item number one.
            }else if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomProfile) {
                // The user selected item number one.
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initView(){

    viewPager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    fragAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), currentUser, context);
    viewPager.setAdapter(fragAdapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
    // lose the current tab on orientation change.
    mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void setPage(final int pageNum){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNum, true);
    Global.setCurrentPageNum(pageNum);
}

private void setAdapterClick(int no){
    switch (no){
        case Constants.CONTACTS_NUM :
            setPage(Constants.CONTACTS_NUM);
            break;
        case Constants.ADD_NUM :
            setPage(Constants.ADD_NUM);
            break;
        case Constants.PROFILE_NUM :
            setPage(Constants.PROFILE_NUM);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

FragmentAdapter.java

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

private Context context;
private User currentUser;
private FragmentManager fm;


public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, User currentUser, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.fm = fm;
    this.context = context;
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0 :
            return new ContactsFragment().newInstance(context, currentUser);
        case 1 :
            return new ContactsFragment().newInstance(context, currentUser);
        case 2 :
            return new ProfileFragment().newInstance(context, currentUser);
        default :
            return new ContactsFragment().newInstance(context, currentUser);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

One of my Fragments:

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment{
// Store instance variables
private Context context;
private User currentUser;
private View actionView;
private View contactsView;

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static ContactsFragment newInstance(Context context, User currentUser) {
    ContactsFragment fragmentFirst = new ContactsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("currentUser", currentUser);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.context = getActivity();
    this.currentUser = (User) getArguments().getSerializable("currentUser");

}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(contactsView == null){
        contactsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_layout, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) contactsView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(context, 1);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, R.drawable.divider));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(context, currentUser.categories));
    }
    return contactsView;
}
}
```

Edit: 
If I disable animation while setting current item, there is no problem. But I want to use animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line after you setting adapter for your ViewPager in initView()

```
viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(3);
```

The following method is alreday provided by ViewPager class in Android

```
    /**
 * Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
 * current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
 * limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
 *
 * <p>This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
 * of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in place
 * on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in perceived smoothness
 * of paging animations and interaction. If you have a small number of pages (3-4)
 * that you can keep active all at once, less time will be spent in layout for
 * newly created view subtrees as the user pages back and forth.</p>
 *
 * <p>You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex layouts.
 * This setting defaults to 1.</p>
 *
 * @param limit How many pages will be kept offscreen in an idle state.
 */
public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
    if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " +
                DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
        limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
    }
    if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
        mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
        populate();
    }
}
```

One More thing I have noticed inside your code is that you are using **getIntentSearializableExtra()** cuz you are using **Serializable** to transport data inside your activity and also in Fragment.

Please Don't Do this try to use Serializable Use **Parcelable** and **getParcelableExtra()**

Please consider this link http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development

this is why i am suggesting you to use **Parcelable**.

Comment: Thans for your answer but it didn't work. There is still laggy swipe between fragments.

Comment: @EmreAlparslan you tried it with 2 or 3 i hurriedly written 2 but you are using 3 fragments so try it with 3